# Creating Acoustic models for Microsoft speech recognition engine

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-platform

Is it possible to create acoustic models for Micorosoft speech recognition engine like the same way we do for CMU Sphinx

CMUSphinx link :  http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt

I have searched a bit but havent found a suitable answer or solution for it.

Can anyone point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Acoustic adaptation can be done via the Windows Control Panel; search for "speech", and you will find the Speech Recognition control panel, which has an item 'Train your computer to better understand you'. Running this will result in an improved acoustic model.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Will i be able to give approx 15 lakh input words to my machine

Comment: @VipinNair Either I'm confused, or you are. :)  Acoustic adaptation adjusts the acoustic model to match a single speaker to known text; when you say you want 1,500,000 words, that makes me think you want a dictation model, not an acoustic model.  You can download the [Dictation Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23262) which will allow you to create new dictation models.

Comment: Its not you ,its me who is confused :). My client wants a proper audio comparison thing and how much i try ,there is only 80% accuracy. Little anxious to make it working

Comment: @VipinNair You might want to invest in some high quality microphones as well.  The typical microphone is subpar; a good quality headset microphone will do wonders.  eMicrophones is a pretty reliable provider.

Comment: thankyou for fast replies. Yes i have already suggested my clients to get good microphones ,but they are not at all agreeing to it.Even i know that code wise nothing else can be done.

Comment: You can also write custom training scripts, but you'll have to do that via C++, as System.Speech doesn't expose the appropriate SAPI interfaces.

Comment: can u provide me any links which provide me an example to do that as i havent done this type of custom trainings before

Comment: It's another dark corner of SAPI.  I wrote a discussion (which is getting much too long) on my [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2013/09/12/displayui-and-the-extra-data-parameters.aspx).